# jar -uf on springboot JAR remove all rest files from archive

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

How to update one file in JAR from Springboot app?
Command `jar uf jar-file input-file` couses update only the input file, all the rest deleted.
I also noticed
`jar -i` not display anything in the +100mb jar.
I'm trying to do couple hotfixes in static files in working production jars without restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

Although I assume you already found an answer, or no longer care; I encountered the same problem and found out that because of the fact that the .jar is a runnable jar, this was the reason.

In my pom.xml I removed the runnable configuration from the spring-boot maven plugin and then it worked.

I changed:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

to:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```